# AWS Lambda is Unable to find app.handler (Custom Docker Image)

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, docker, aws-lambda

I want to deploy machine learning related code on AWS Lambda function as Docker image. Base Images provided by AWS for Python, don't allow to install using apt-get command. So I created custom docker image for AWS Lambda. Below is the code of my Dockerfile.

ref: [Create an image from an alternative base image](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/images-create.html#images-create-2)

```
ARG FUNCTION_DIR="/function"

FROM python:3.7-buster as build-image

# Install aws-lambda-cpp build dependencies
RUN apt-get update && \
  apt-get install -y \
  g++ \
  make \
  cmake \
  unzip \
  libcurl4-openssl-dev

RUN apt-get install -y python-opencv

# Include global arg in this stage of the build
ARG FUNCTION_DIR
# Create function directory
RUN mkdir -p ${FUNCTION_DIR}

# Install the runtime interface client
RUN pip install \
        --target ${FUNCTION_DIR} \
        awslambdaric

FROM python:3.7-buster

ARG FUNCTION_DIR
# Set working directory to function root directory
WORKDIR ${FUNCTION_DIR}

# Copy in the build image dependencies
COPY --from=build-image ${FUNCTION_DIR} ${FUNCTION_DIR}

COPY requirements.txt /
#RUN pip install -r /requirements.txt

COPY .  /function
ENV AWS_LAMBDA_RUNTIME_API=python3.7
ENTRYPOINT [ "/usr/local/bin/python", "-m", "awslambdaric" ]
CMD [ "app.handler" ]
```

My Folder structure is as below:

```
aws_lambda (Folder)
- Dockerfile
- app.py
- function (Folder)
  - app.py
- requirements.txt
```

When I run docker image, it shows error as below:

```
[ERROR] [1614258613176] LAMBDA_RUNTIME Failed to get next invocation. No Response from endpoint
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", mod_spec)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "/function/awslambdaric/__main__.py", line 21, in <module>
    main(sys.argv)
  File "/function/awslambdaric/__main__.py", line 17, in main
    bootstrap.run(app_root, handler, lambda_runtime_api_addr)
  File "/function/awslambdaric/bootstrap.py", line 416, in run
    event_request = lambda_runtime_client.wait_next_invocation()
  File "/function/awslambdaric/lambda_runtime_client.py", line 76, in wait_next_invocation
    response_body, headers = runtime_client.next()
RuntimeError: Failed to get next
Executing 'app.handler' in function directory '/function'
```

It seems it is unable to find /function directory but it is already there.

Comment: Seems to me that the error is somewhere else. Where are you running the container? Is it a local testing or you have deployed?

Comment: Locally works fine. Only doesn't work when deployed.

Comment: have you tried locally with the Runtime Interface Emulator (RIE) ? It doesn't seems to be installed from the dockerfile. Testing with the RIE gives you the same environment of the lambda so you can debug exactly what is happening. Additionally, why are you setting AWS_LAMBDA_RUNTIME_API ? It's not necessary and set automatically by lambda since you are using the python runtime interface client.

Answer (score 5):

I've run into this thing recently and this is what works for me.

My dockerfile:

```
ARG FUNCTION_DIR="/opt/myapp"

FROM ubuntu:16.04

RUN apt update \
    && apt upgrade \
    && apt-get install -y software-properties-common python-software-properties \
    && apt-add-repository -y ppa:deadsnakes/ppa \
    && apt update \
    && apt-get install -y python3.6 python3.6-dev python3-pip

RUN python3.6 -m pip --no-cache-dir install awslambdaric
ADD https://github.com/aws/aws-lambda-runtime-interface-emulator/releases/latest/download/aws-lambda-rie /usr/bin/aws-lambda-rie

ARG FUNCTION_DIR
RUN mkdir -p ${FUNCTION_DIR}
WORKDIR /opt
ADD myapp myapp
COPY entry.sh /opt/myapp/entry.sh
RUN chmod 755 /usr/bin/aws-lambda-rie /opt/myapp/entry.sh
WORKDIR /tmp
ENTRYPOINT [ "/opt/myapp/entry.sh" ]
CMD [ "/opt/myapp/app.handler" ]
```

My entrypoint

```
#!/bin/sh

if [ -z "${AWS_LAMBDA_RUNTIME_API}" ]; then
    exec /usr/bin/aws-lambda-rie /usr/bin/python3.6 -m awslambdaric $1
else
    exec /usr/bin/python3.6 -m awslambdaric $1
fi
```

Then I built my image with:

> docker build --rm -t myimage .

And tested locally running with:

> docker run -p 9000:8080 --rm -it myimage:latest

In another terminal I run:

> curl -XPOST
> "http://localhost:9000/2015-03-31/functions/function/invocations" -d
> '{"field1":"..", "field2":".."}'

Elaboration starts. My `app.py` contain a method `handler`, which parse the argument event and retrieve the fields (you can see them in the curl call), then starts the elaboration. I set my workdir in `/tmp` because it's the only read/write folder in AWS Lambda so I can put there some intermediate files of my elaboration.

Comment: This answer is correct, but it helps tremendously to read the AWS blog from which this answer originated: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-for-aws-lambda-container-image-support/.

Comment: I have very similar code to this post but when I call the lambda function locally I get this error: Unable to unmarshal input: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0), has anyone else run into this problem using the code above and know of a solution?

Comment: I guess there is an issue in the curl command, maybe you are not escaping correclty.. can you open a new question with the exact code and command you are using ?

Comment: Hi @rok, What does the `ADD myapp myapp` do? That cannot be found in my app. Moreover, I didn't see the COPY app.py in your Dockerfile. Thanks

Comment: ADD is nearly equivalent to COPY, see the docs for the differences, but basically is used to copy a folder inside the container..